# auto_complete feature not using filter_plugin_options when using yadcf

Tags: yadcf

I am using the auto_complete feature in yadcf plugin. I want to set the minLength for it, but on setting it the option does not seem to reflect on the page.

Please have a look at my code

```
yadcf.init(table,
[{
column_number : 0,
filter_type : "auto_complete",
filter_container_id: "selName",
filter_default_label : "Type Name",
cumulative_filtering : true,
filter_reset_button_text : "",
reset_button_style_class : "searchicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle",
filter_match_mode : "startsWith",
filter_plugin_options :{
    minLength : 3
}
});
```

can you please let me know what I have missed and what changes I need to do?

Comment: you haven't missed a thing, apparently I missed it, its a bug which I will fix and release in a day or two, if you will open an issue with test page it will speed things up https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues

Comment: Thanks for making the fix, but right now I am facing 2 issues. 
1)filter_match_mode: "startsWith" is not working. I checked with filter type as text, the match mode works but not with auto_complete. It does not work even if remove filter_plugin_options.
2) yadcf 0.9.4 beta version is not working with iPad 2 model mc982hn/a. So just to see whether even previous versions had this issue I tried 0.9.3 again it did not work on this iPad model while 0.9.2 works fine. But only on this device the code does not work, It works fine on iPhone, iPad (5th generation). Can you please help